# .Net Core 2.0 IServiceProvider eager initialization

Tags: c#, .net-core

A little background:

In my current project I am attempting to work with .Net Core 2.0 DI system for dependency injection. I am using [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) for Assembly scanning and adding all classes that implement a given interface to a IServiceCollection in order to build the IServiceProvider. Something similar to the example in the github.

```
 public static IServiceCollection AddSingletonsFromAssembly(this 
               IServiceCollection collection, Type type, Assembly assembly)
 {
      collection.Scan(x =>
      {
         x.FromAssemblies(assembly)
           .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(type))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces()
           .WithSingletonLifetime();
       });
        return collection;
 }
```

The problem I am running into now is that some of my services are not needed by any other service and therefor are never initialized by the IServiceProvider being IServiceProvider lazily initializes singletons.

Is there a way to set IServiceProvider to eagerly initialization or to iterate the services in a IServiceProvider in order to initialize them?

I fill the collection with an empty generic interface so using GetServices is not an option here because you can not have a list of empty generics.

I am open to additional dependencies if they are small.

NOTE: This is .Net Core Console App...   not ASP.NET Core

Forgot to mention. I know I can go through and do a real quick `IServiceProvider.GetService<T>()` to initialize these instances, but I would prefer a write once and forget way of doing it. Similiar to the assembly scanning.

Comment: If nothing ever needs those services, then why do you need to initialize them?

Comment: They are more of say vent handler...  They use other services to register for the services events but as it sits currently no other service has a current use for them besides just passing events off to them.
I think however you may have just made me think of an answer on my own. Instead of injecting services into my handlers to add to the services OnEvent Func..  I should probably be injecting the handler and setting that in the service.
Still interested in a good way to eagerly initialize the singleton lifetime though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll answer with what I came up with.

The way I decided to handle this is to tag the services that run on their own and not used by any other service with a empty interface of `IEagerSingleton` and don't tag them with the empty generic that I use for my other services `IService<T>`.

This allows me to still get the dependency injection for all the services that are used elsewhere while being able to eagerly initialize the ones I want to be eagerly initialized. Basic idea below.

```
public interface ISingleton<T>
{}

public interface IEagerSingleton
{}

public class Singleton : IEagerSingleton
{

}

//In a startup method somewhere
var collection = new
ServiceCollection().AddSingletonsFromAssembly(typeof(IEagerSingleton));
collection.AddSingletonsFromAssembly(typeof(ISingleton<>));

var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
provider.GetServices<IEagerSingleton>();
```

Doing it this way, my already working injections still work and now the services that rely on injection from the ServiceProvider but are not used by any other service get eagerly initialized. Plus it is still maintainable with little effort. If one of the other services ends up needing one of the stand alone services later, I can simply swap the interface that service inherits from to a `ISingleton<T>`.